# Filter field returns all records when search is empty

Tags: laravel

When I don't insert anything in the search field, all the records in my table return, I don't want that to happen, how can I do so that it doesn't return any results if `$search = $request->input('search');` is empty?

```
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->input('search');
        $client = ClientModel::where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")->get();
        return view('search', compact('client'));
    }
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure where exactly the problem is, basically what you described in your question. Check if `$search` is empty, return no results. Else, return the results

Answer (score 1):

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->input('search');
        if(!empty($search)){
          $client = ClientModel::where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")->get(); 
          return view('search', compact('client'));
        }else{
           $client = [];
           return view('search', compact('client'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can simplify using a ternary: $client = (!empty($search) ? ClientModel::where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")->get() : []);

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

```php
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $client = array();
        if($request->filled('search')){
          $search = $request->input('search');
          $client = ClientModel::where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")->get(); 
        }
        return view('search', compact('client'));
    }
```

Please use <kbd>fillled</kbd> method to check the data present in the GET Super Global variable if data is there then run your query otherwise return an empty array.

Thanks